# Remove wordpress Default Template only from Custom Posts

Tags: php, wordpress

In my Wordpress site, I have created custom post types. For those custom posts, I created post templates such as Template 1, Template 2, and Template 3.

Wordpress default gives a post template called “Default Template” and now the Post Attributes drop down loads as follows.

- Default Template
- Template 1
- Template 2
- Template 3

**I want to remove “Default Template” only from Custom Post Types.** 
(Note: “Default Template” should be available Wordpress Default Posts.)

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I think that you can find the solution [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/264233/change-delete-the-default-post-type-and-category) and also I think that you should post that type of question (wordpress) in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Ok. Thanks - @F.Lazarescu